# How to write list of number with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, office-interop

I need to write an array of string to a numbered list but on a specific location.
For example, the array is:

```
sentence[0] : Joe Greer
sentence[1] : Alayah Misasau
sentence[2] : Nick Underwood
sentence[3] : Mike Jacob
sentence[4] : Jared Swift
...
```

Then it should be written on a specific location, let's say under the section heading "A. Student's Name"

```
 A. Student's Name
     1.  Joe Greer
     2.  Alayah Misasau
     3.  Nick Underwood
     4.  Mike Jacob
     5.  Jared swift
```

My logic so far is using a unique tags, then it will be replaced and looped by the array to be written on a numbered list. Let's say the unique tag is   ######STUDENTSNAME#####. I don't know how to code this, lack of documentation for this on google.

How am I supposed to do to code this on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word?

P.S. : I have a template document .doc/.docx for the only section headings, then I just need to fill it with the numbered list.

Comment: I fully agree with Clint's remarks. That said, research the concept of Bookmarks in Word. Beyond that, I recommend performing the actions in the Word UI and recording a macro. That will give you the basic syntax (object, properties, methods) to get you started. Please read the guidelines in the [help] about what kinds of questions are on-target on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use Office interop modules on a server application.  You really shouldn't even install them on a server.  Those modules were never intended for server side use.  See [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757).  In the "Alternatives to server-side Automation" section of that article they state:

> Microsoft strongly recommends that developers find alternatives to Automation of Office if they need to develop server-side solutions

They can and will cause slow response times and memory leakage.  I've seen web servers that had to be restarted daily because of the severe memory leakage these modules caused.

Microsoft recommends using Open XML instead of Office interop in server applications.  At the bottom of the article linked above there are many links to Open XML resources.